# JSOUP missing tag when converting html row

Tags: java, jsoup

I having problem with jsoup whereby i want to get a row of data which later I will be inserting the row into another html document. But when i inspect time saw that there is no  and  tag. How can i solve it

```
String htmlcontent = "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><strong><span class=\"CLASS 1 CLASS 2 CLASS 3\">123</span></strong><br /><strong>DATA 1</strong></p></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>";


Document docnewinput = Jsoup.parse(htmlcontent, "UTF-8");
```

```
[<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
   <p><strong><span class="CLASS 1 CLASS 2 CLASS 3">123</span></strong><br><strong>DATA 1</strong></p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fragment of body HTML (e.g. a div containing a couple of p tags; as opposed to a full HTML document) that you want to parse.

Use the `Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(String html)` method.

```
String html = "<table><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><strong><span class=\"CLASS 1 CLASS 2 CLASS 3\">123</span></strong><br /><strong>DATA 1</strong></p></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
```

The `parseBodyFragment` method creates an empty shell document, and inserts the parsed HTML into the body element. If you used the normal `Jsoup.parse(String html)` method, you would generally get the same result, but explicitly treating the input as a body fragment ensures that any bozo HTML provided by the user is parsed into the body element.

The parser will make every attempt to create a clean parse from the HTML you provide, regardless of whether the HTML is well-formed or not. It handles:
unclosed tags `(e.g. <p>Lorem <p>Ipsum parses to <p>Lorem</p> <p>Ipsum</p>)`
implicit tags `(e.g. a naked <td>Table data</td> is wrapped into a <table><tr><td>...)`
reliably creating the document structure (html containing a head and body, and only appropriate elements within the head)

EDIT:

By using Jsoup.parse():

```
String html = "<table><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><strong><span class=\"CLASS 1 CLASS 2 CLASS 3\">123</span></strong><br /><strong>DATA 1</strong></p></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Working Demo: https://try.jsoup.org/~EdJSrHl_biDcQkyhL2BLH5ZNnck

Comment: Hi, still same the tr, td tag is not appearing

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Did you tried using Jsoup.parse(). This should work. Updated the answer with details.

Comment: Hi, i tried add this  Parser.xmlParser() then it works

Comment: Based on you comment if u try <tr><td colspan=\"2\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><strong><span class=\"CLASS 1 CLASS 2 CLASS 3\">123</span></strong><br /><strong>DATA 1</strong></p></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> it will not work. so need use the xmlParser

Answer (score 0):

Need to use xmlParser() so that it will just read the string as it without formatting it.